# Executing pnputil commands via C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm trying to execute pnputil commands via C#

When I execute plain command on Powershell, it's successful.

```
pnputil /disable-device "USB\VID_054C&PID_06C3\0500624"
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WI45o.png

But if I run this command from C#, it fails

```
using (var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process())
        {
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.FileName = @"Powershell.exe";
            startInfo.Arguments = "/c pnputil /disable-device \"USB\\VID_054C&PID_06C3\\0500624\"";
            startInfo.Verb = "runas";
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();
        }
```

This code returns the following error:

> The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double quotation marks ("&") to pass it as part of a string.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnPNM.png

How can I fix the C# code?

Comment: By not mixing in PowerShell, because that doesn't do anything meaningful in this scenario. Just invoke `pnputil` directly.

Comment: How do I do that ?

You mean I change the code like that?

startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\pnputil.exe";
                startInfo.Arguments = "/disable-device \"USB\\VID_054C&PID_06C3\\0500624\"";
                startInfo.Verb = "runas";

Comment: Replace `powershell.exe` with `pnputil.exe` and remove `/c pnputil` from the argument list. The quotes around the argument are then probably no longer necessary, but I'm not sure about that (the rules on argument quoting are a nightmare).

Comment: I managed to solve this problem using SetupAPI.